# Close Reason: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network

Tags: feature-request, closing-questions, migration

While voting to close [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/38678/5184), I considered the close reason "**This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network**".

But when I clicked that, the only option it gave me was that it belongs on [meta.scifi](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com) - and clicking that option was required to use that close reason.

I ended up using the custom close reason, but it seems like the "belongs on other" should have other options besides meta.

Someone previously suggested that we [add physics.se as an option for close reasons](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2624/add-physics-se-as-an-option-for-questions-that-dont-belong-here?rq=1), and the arguments against it make sense, but as-is, the "belongs on other" doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: [This](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3040/a-remedial-lesson-for-those-who-have-vtc-powers/3041#3041) question is another good example of where the ability to vote to migrate somewhere other than meta rather than vote to close would have prevented a contentious discussion on its merits on this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That page is how questions are migrated between Stack Exchange sites.  Regular users only have the ability to migrate to sites that have 'migration paths' setup to other graduated Stack Exchange sites.  Since the obvious sites we would migrate to are in beta (Movies & TV, and Anime), we don't have any migration paths setup, ergo the only option you see is migrating to Meta.

Mods have the ability to do migrations to any other site, including beta sites.  We've used this to migrate a few non-sci-fi/fantasy questions over to Movies & TV.

Comment: We can't add a migration path to Beta sites?  That seems a little odd.  Don't they want questions to grow the site?

Comment: @Izkata Beta sites can (and do) fail, so it makes sense to not encourage transferring a bunch of questions to them.  Once a site graduates, it's ostensibly a permanent fixture, so transferring questions there lacks the risk of the questions vanishing if the site is closed.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the "other" off-topic close reason:

[image: close]

> This question appears to be off-topic because it is about dentists. This could be on-topic at [Toothdecay.SE]. Do not re-post there, the moderators will migrate the question for you.

You can then flag the question for moderator attention and ask for it to be migrated.

And please only do this when the question is good enough to be migrated. We don't migrate crappy questions.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. It just felt odd since there was an option specifically for belonging on another SE site.

Comment: @phantom42: That's primarily for sites that have dedicated migration paths, such as Stack Overflow to Super Users, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I almost asked this same question about a week ago, but found this instead:  [Migration Paths](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1030/migration-paths)

It's nearly 2 years old, but the reasoning there almost still seems appropriate:  We *still* have had only [nine migrations in the last 90 days](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats):

- 1 from Skeptics to SciFi
- 3 from SciFi to Movies
- 2 from SciFi to Space
- 1 from SciFi to Biology
- 1 from SciFi to English
- 1 from SciFi (Main) to SciFi (Meta)

However, in the past week, I'm thinking it may be time to rethink that decision.  These stats, I'm pretty certain are incorrect.  There've been a couple recent questions that probably should have been migrated to Movies.SE, except that option wasn't in the list so we just closed it as "Off Topic" with a custom reason.  (Such as [this one, still on the front page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/38678/tv-series-about-creating-games) - Movies.SE has an [identify-this-tv-show tag](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-tv-show))

I would propose, at the very least, adding Movies.SE to the migration list once it's out of Beta.

Comment: Do you think it would make sense to add a custom option to the "belongs on other" close path?

Comment: @phantom42 As far as I know, it's strictly limited to a pre-chosen list of a maximum of 5 sites, no custom selections (and Meta doesn't have to be one of them; it simply makes sense as one)

Comment: @Izkata Meta does have to be one of the options. There can be up to 5 other sites, but they have to be justified by volume. Even if a few migrations didn't happen because nobody thought of flagging, No site has received even 1 migration per month, this is far short of justifying a migration path.

Comment: Adding [movies.se] as a migration path would be problematic, because questions about SF movies are on-topic here and should not be migrated. Moderators regularly get flags to migrate on-topic questions just because they would also be on-topic on the other site; adding an unsupervised opportunity for migration would result in on-topic questions being migrated away.

Comment: @Gilles Does the community voting for migration to meta automatically cause the migration to occur? I figured it still took action on the part of mods.

Comment: @phantom42: Anyone with close reputation can migrate a question to Meta, at least, with the help of 4 other such people. Mods don't need to get involved.

Comment: For an example, see http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24825/what-is-the-meaning-of-spoiler?noredirect=1

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto That was back during General Reference debates, I think I had VTC'd as such.  I also didn't realize it bypassed mods, I had thought it was similar to avoiding the custom flag options when possible - it would get closed, then mods would be notified in a standardized way that a migration needed to happen.

Comment: @Gilles Up to 4 other sites. The limit is 5 *including* meta.